# Notifications and sending object values - beginners help please

Tags: objective-c, operating-system

Ive set up a notification centre with the following code in a class called ConnectionController

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(aChangeCalendarMethod:) name:@"updateCalendar" object:nil];
```

And have a sender in another class (MonthFieldValidator)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateCalendar" object:self];
```

MonthFieldValidator has a property of NSString type called month which I want to pass the value of back to connection controller.

All I seem to be able to do is get this

Printing description of testObject:
(NSObject *) testObject = 0x4055c00000000000

And the object doesn't have the month property (or at least that I can access).

Presumably I will have to useruser info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateCalendar" object:yourMonthStringHere];
```

Method that will be called is:

```
-(void)aChangeCalendarMethod:(NSNotification*)notification
{
   NSString *strMonth = (NSString *)[notification object]; //retrieve passed string like this
   //continue other code

}
```